# Problems transforming special characters to bytes and strings

Tags: java, encoding

I'm showing a dropdown on a web page but when using characters as ○ as options, the dropdown shows a question mark

I'm getting the dropdown option from a SQL Server database in which the column that saves the value is nvarchar type
Then I create an XML output string with the values to send it as response of an AJAX call

When I do  xmlWriter.toString() , being xmlWriter a StringWriter object, I'm able to see the ○ character using Eclipse's debug mode but that string needs to be sent as a ByteArrayOutputStream object to add it to response stream for the response to see the XML file on the client side but when doing xmlWriter.toString().getBytes() the ○ character becomes a question mark

I've tried to use xmlWriter.toString().getBytes("UTF-8") but the result is some strange symbols

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

By guessing what might be your problem it feels like you're not specifying the encoding in your response object to the browser and it fails guessing the right one. Consider calling `getBytes("UTF-8")` as you did (better: `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`) and submit an encoding information along with your response, either in the HTTP header (`Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8`) as you're probably using HTTP or in the XML header (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`). Maybe even both as this will provide you the best compatibility.

Comment: I do add the http header and the xml header with charset and encoding as utf-8 respectively but the moment the getBytes is executed, checking on debug mode, the ByteArrayOutputStream shows the white circle as question mark